# async.waterfall duplicates calls

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, coffeescript, async.js

I have the below async code.

```
  for fileName in sourceFiles
    console.log 'dealing with ', fileName
    async.waterfall [
      (callback) ->
        console.log "going to read ", fileName
        fs.readFile fileName, (err, content) ->
          if err then throw err
          callback null, fileName, content
          return
      (fileName, content, callback) ->
        console.log 'length of: ',  fileName, ' is: ', content.length
```

I expected that the output will be something like:

```
dealing with file1
going to read file1
length of file1 is 10
dealing with file2
going to read file2
length of file 2 is 20
```

instead, what I get is this:

```
dealing with file1
dealing with file2
going to read file2
going to read file2 <- note it is the same file repeated
length of file2 is 20
length of file2 is 20
```

I'm not able to figure out why this would be so. (This being a coffeescript is no issue. It is the same output in JS too)

Answer (score 1):

The `async` library doesn't duplicate the calls, but you have an issue with scoping here.

The `fileName` in your loop already is set to `file2` when your first function is called you should try to wrap that into another function, just to get a new scope to work with, like this:

```
for fileName in sourceFiles
  (fileName) ->
    console.log 'dealing with ', fileName
    async.waterfall [
      (callback) ->
        console.log "going to read ", fileName
        fs.readFile fileName, (err, content) ->
          if err then throw err
          callback null, fileName, content
          return
      (fileName, content, callback) ->
        console.log 'length of: ',  fileName, ' is: ', content.length
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that async.waterfall is asynchronous too so your loop is terminated before the waterfall callback and waterfall is called 2 times with the same fileName.

But here, waterfall is useless, you can simply use readFileSync who is synchronous.

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options